IN elixir with Postgres, how to generate_series and convert from 'UTC' to another zone?
I am trying to do a time series and convert what is 'utc' time into another zone.
I have this code in Elixir:
 sd =  ~U[2024-07-31 05:00:00.000000Z]
 ed =  ~U[2024-08-02 04:59:59.000999Z]
 timezone = "US/Central"

 from(
            c in fragment(
              "SELECT generate_series(now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE ?, (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE ?) - CAST(? AS INTERVAL), '-1 hour') AS entry",
              ^timezone,
              ^timezone,
              ^%Postgrex.Interval{secs: DateTime.diff(ed, sd)}
            ),
            select: %{
              date_str:
                fragment(
                  "to_char(? AT TIME ZONE ?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ')",
                  c.entry,
                  ^timezone
                )
            }
          )

I get these results in utc instead of the zone I expect: I want 'US/central' not "" or 'UTC'

     data: [
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 16:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 15:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 14:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 13:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 12:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 11:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 10:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 09:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 08:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 07:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 06:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 05:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 04:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 03:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 02:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 01:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-08-01 00:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 23:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 22:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 21:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 20:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 19:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 18:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 17:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 16:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 15:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 14:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 13:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 12:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 11:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 10:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 09:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 08:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 07:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 06:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 05:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 04:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 03:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 02:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 01:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-31 00:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-30 23:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-30 22:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-30 21:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-30 20:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-30 19:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-30 18:21:21 "},
        %{date_str: "2024-07-30 17:21:21 "}
      ]

This code change results in 'utc'
 from(
            c in fragment(
              "SELECT generate_series(now() AT TIME ZONE ?, (now() AT TIME ZONE ?) - CAST(? AS INTERVAL), '-1 hour') AS entry",
              ^timezone,
              ^timezone,
              ^%Postgrex.Interval{secs: DateTime.diff(range.end_date, range.start_date)}
            ),
            select: %{
              date_str:
                fragment(
                  "to_char(? AT TIME ZONE ?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ')",
             )                   )

new results:
  %{date_str: "2024-08-01 17:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 16:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 15:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 14:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 13:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 12:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 11:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 10:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 09:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 08:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 07:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 06:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 05:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 04:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 03:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 02:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 01:24:22 UTC"},
    %{date_str: "2024-08-01 00:24:22 UTC"},



What is TimeZone set to for the server. 2) All those AT TIME ZONE's are not helping. 3) Why not set TimeZone  = 'US/Central', then something like select generate_series(now(), now() - '1 day'::interval, '-1 hour');?


all the server times are utc, but each client in the db can have a timezone and I need to build up a series from utc times to the customers zone. all those details have been stripped out for simplicity.

So, for each client start a session, change the session timezone to the clients, run the generate_series().

turns out tz in to_char() is not well supported in postgres for the long version of a zone like 'US/Central' or others. The OF [for offset] works fine.
this worked for me:
from(
            c in fragment(
              "SELECT generate_series(now() AT TIME ZONE ?, (now() AT TIME ZONE ?) - CAST(? AS INTERVAL), '-1 hour') AS entry",
              ^timezone,
              ^timezone,
              ^%Postgrex.Interval{secs: DateTime.diff(range.end_date, range.start_date)}
            ),
            select: %{
              date_str:
                fragment(
                  "to_char(? AT TIME ZONE ?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS')",
                  c.entry,
                  ^timezone
                )
            }
          )
                                                       )

